# Get difference between last two values of an RxJS Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable tracking the scroll position

```
 const scroll = Observable
  .fromEvent(document, 'scroll')
  .map(e => window.pageYOffset)
  .startWith(0)
```

I would like to have a second observable tracking the scroll delta `(newScroll - lastScroll)`

```
const scrollDelta = scroll
  // ???
  .subscribe(delta => console.log('delta:', delta) )
```

How to implement something like this?
I've tried with scan with no success.
Thx

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [pairwise](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise):

```
scroll
    .pairwise()
    .map(([a, b]) => b - a);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it if our observed variable is an Object ? I would like to retrieve the diff of previous value and current value, is it somehow possible to do that ?

Answer (score 11):

Old question, but to add info for RxJS version 5, where the API surface has changed somewhat and it took me some time to find the answer: the equivalent to `pairwise` would be `bufferWithCount(2,1)` (v4) or `bufferCount(2,1)` (v5).

Comment: Its added again in beta1. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/commit/1432e59

Comment: Thanks for the info. It can sometimes take a bit of time to track down the names of the renamed operators.